Are phonon position and momentum operators self-adjoint?
I am currently doing a calculation which involves phonons and decided to try to follow every detail regarding the quantization of the phonons.
Lets suppose we have a collection of atoms in a crystal, with $N$ unit cells and $Z$ atoms per cell. Let $U_\alpha^{m,i}$ be the $\alpha$th coordinate of the atom in cell $m$ and position $i$ in that cell, with respect to its equilibrium position. When we perform the quantization, as far as I am aware, $U_\alpha^{m,i}$ will obey the cannonical commutation relations:
$$
[U_\alpha^{m,i},U_\beta^{n,j}] = 0; [P_\alpha^{m,i},P_\beta^{n,j}] = 0;\ \ [U_\alpha^{m,i},P_\beta^{n,j}] = i\hbar \delta_{\alpha,\beta}\delta_{m,n}\delta_{i,j}.
$$
Before I continue, let me remark the following properties which are very usefull when dealing with a periodic system:
$$
\sum_ke^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot(\mathbf{R}_n-\mathbf{R}_m)} = N\delta_{nm};\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \sum_me^{i(\mathbf{k}-\mathbf{k}')\cdot\mathbf{R}_m} = N\delta_{kk'}.
$$
There are several procedures to perform the phonon quantization. I will be following the ones performed in 'Lattice Dynamics of Molecular crystals' by G.Berthier and 'Atomic and Electronic structure of solids' by E.Kaxiras.
First we expand the potential up to second order, arriving at the equations of motion for the displacements $U_\alpha^{m,i}$, and finally absorbing the mass dependance by the definition of $W_\alpha^{m,i} = \sqrt{m_i}U_\alpha^{m,i}$. The equations of motion for the mass-weigthed displacements become 'mass symmetric' and the typical travelling wave solution is used.
After some calculations, the Hamiltonian can be diagonalized in terms of the $Q_{p,\mathbf{k}}$ coordinates, which correspond to phonons of the 'p' branch associated with the wave-vector $\mathbf{k}$. It can be shown that the Q coordinates can be expressed in terms of the original displacements $U_\alpha^{m,i}$ as:
$$
Q_{p,\mathbf{k}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_{\alpha,m,i}e^{-i\mathbf{k}\cdot \mathbf{R}_m}\sqrt{m_i}U_\alpha^{m,i}e_{\alpha}(i|p\mathbf{k}),
$$
where $e_{\alpha}(i|p\mathbf{k})$ is the $\alpha$th component of the eigenvector of the 'p' branch associated with the wave-vector $\mathbf{k}$ which contributes to the movement of the particle i of a cell.
My question lays here: If the operators $U_\alpha^{m,i}$ are self adjoint, then Q_{p,\mathbf{k}} can't be self adjoint right? Or am I missing something?
In fact, if I am not wrong, it also holds that
$$
Q_{p,\mathbf{k}}^\dagger = Q_{p,-\mathbf{k}}.
$$
If Q is not self adjoint, isn't it a problem? Before I looked into the details, I thought Q was like the position of the phonons, but withouht beeing a self-adjoint operator I am doubting this interpretation is valid.
Is this a manifestation that phonons are not actually real particles but pseudo-particles?
What is true is that the Hamiltonian is diagonalized by these Q
$$
H = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{p,\mathbf{k}}(P_{p,\mathbf{k}}P_{p,\mathbf{k}}^\dagger + {\omega^2}_{p,\mathbf{k}}  Q_{p,\mathbf{k}}^\dagger Q_{p,\mathbf{k}}) 
$$
where $P_{p,\mathbf{k}} = \dot{Q}_{p,-\mathbf{k}}= \dot{Q}_{p,\mathbf{k}}^\dagger$  (to ensure the commutation relations hold).
And if the commutation relations hold, then the ladder operator algebra is still valid and behave as harmonic oscillators.
I am grateful to any insight given. My apologies in advanced if the post is not clear enough.

What kind of answer do you expect? You already pointed out that $Q$ is not self-adjoint.

My real concern is about the consequences of Q not being self adjoint. Repeating the question in text:
If Q is not self adjoint, isn't it a problem? Before I looked into the details, I thought Q was like the position of the phonons, but withouht beeing a self-adjoint operator I am doubting this interpretation is valid.
Is this a manifestation that phonons are not actually real particles but pseudo-particles?
Another concern I have is that the Hamiltonian is similar to an harmonic oscillator but the 'momentum' and 'position' are very different (continue)

In a 'real' harmonic oscillator both the position and momentum operators are self-adjoint, while in the Hamiltonian for the phonons this is not true. It seems odd to me that there are no consequences arising from this difference, and even more strange that the energy spectrum is the same for both. I guess it has to do with the algebra of the ladder operators but still I was wondering if there is deeper meaning to it.
